# Laravel: I'm adding a specialty to each therapist in my database and this shows up. Why?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

[image]

```
<?php


public function up()
{
    Schema::create('specialties', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name')->unique;
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('t_specialties', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->integer('therapist_id');
        $table->integer('spec_id');
        $table->primary(['therapist_id','spec_id']);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('specialties');
    Schema::dropIfExists('t_specialties');
}
```

And my model looks like this

```
class Therapist extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['image'] ;

    public function specialty()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Specialty::class);
    }
}
```

The method I'm using is similar to adding Tags in a blog but every time I try to tinker in cmd, I end up with the error in the photo above. I can't seem to understand what's the problem :(

Comment: can you provide all model details so ican understan your question better and also provide database column names

Answer (score 0):

Never mind answering. I found the solution already. I changed some stuff in my model!

This is the model I first used

```
class Therapist extends Model
{
 protected $fillable = ['image'] ;

 public function specialty()
 {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Specialty::class);
 }
}
```

I updated it to this

```
    public function specialty()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Specialty', 't_specialties', 'therapist_id', 'spec_id');
}
```